# AWS Lamba new project compilation error on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin, aws-lambda, requesthandler

Every time I create a new AWS Lambda Java Project in `Eclipse` using [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/lambda-tutorial.html), I get the following compilation error.

[image: compilation-error-screenshot]

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class MyHandler implements RequestHandler<Object, Object> {

    @Override
    public Object handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

        // TODO: implement your handler
        return null;
     }
}
```

pom.xml looks as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myfirstlambda</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.127</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have other projects that were previously created by my colleague and they seem to have the exact same structure and they work absolutely fine on my `Eclipse`. They also work when I have tried matching the dependencies between the two projects and everything is the exact same.

More than that, I would like to believe that if something that comes out of a template should not have compilation errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show full screenshot (entire class including imports).

Comment: Updated with full code and pom.xml for dependencies